# WordPressのサイトが開かなくなりました

Tags: wordpress

初めまして、sakuと申します。

WordPressのサイトを今回初めて立ち上げたのですが、昨日9:35頃に突然アクセスできなくなりました。wordpressの問合せフォーラムへのログイン・トピック立てもできませんでした。

さくらインターネットサーバーを使用していますが、サーバーの方は「問題なし」とのこと。
WP側の問題だとは分かったのですが・・英語もプログラムも素人すぎて、何をしたらいいのかわかりません。どなたか助けていただけないでしょうか。。

複数のサイトを運営しておりますので、それぞれの症状を下記に書かせていただきます。
いつもwp-adminのアドレスにアクセスしていました。

■サイト①：プラグインを更新(9:11頃)してからしばらくして入れなくなりました。HTTP ERROR 500です。
当初は以下のエラーでした。

```
Warning:require(/サイトアドレス/wp-includes/rest-aph/endpoints/class-wp-rest-post-type-controller.php):failed to open stream:No such file or directory in /サイトアドレス/wp-settings.php on line 229
```

調べてみると、確かにwp-settings.phpではrest-apiで呼び出すようになっているのに、フォルダがrest-aphになっていました。
バックアップを取ってからフォルダ名をapiに変えようとしていたのですが、少し時間を空けて見直すとapiに戻っていました。でもサイトを開くと同じエラーが出ます。

wp-settings.phpの方で、適当に文字を打って消し、上書き保存したところ、今度は沢山のエラーが出てしまいました。

更新したプラグインのフォルダをさくらサーバーのファイルマネージャー上で削除しましたが、解決しません。

現在出ているエラー↓

```
(※)・Notice: Undefined index: capabilities in /home/サイト/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php on line 279
・Notice: Undefined index: originals_lenghts_addr in /home/サイト/wp/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 220(と223)
・Notice: Undefined index: total in /home/shoei-koho/サイト/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 220(と223)
・WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wpebac63options WHERE option_name = 'logged_in_key' LIMIT 1' at line 1]
SELECT option_value FROMwpebac63options WHERE option_name = 'logged_in_key' LIMIT 1
・Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/サイト/wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php:599 Stack trace: #0 /home/サイト/wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php(715): WP->query_posts() #1 /home/サイト/wp/wp-includes/functions.php(960): WP->main('') #2 /home/サイト/wp/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp() #3 /home/サイト/wp/index.php(17): require('/home/サイト...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/サイト/wp/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 599
```

database errorは、これは▼の箇所に半角スペースが足りないのでしょうか？
どこにこの構文があるのかわからず・・。何が問題で何をすればよいのでしょうか。

■サイト②：昨日はサイトが開かず、アクセス権限がないというエラーが出ました。本日さくらのwebフォントのプラグインを削除したところ、ログインができるようになりましたが、上記エラーの※が出ていてロゴマークをクリックしても管理画面に入れません。

■サイト③：何もしていませんが管理画面に入れません。サイト②と同じ症状です。
■サイト④：同じサーバーですが別ドメインで作成したサイトです。サイト②と同じ症状です。

・サーバー：さくらインターネットサーバー
・ブラウザ：chrome、IE11
・WPバージョン：最新(4.9.8) 使い始めたのは9月からです。
・データベースバージョン：MySQL 5.7
・現在プラグインフォルダは「plugins_old」とし、無効化中。
・キャッシュはすべてクリアにしてみました。
・共通のエラーのclass-wp-roles.phpの該当文は[image: class-wp-roles.php line279]です。

どなたかご意見頂戴できますでしょうか。
最悪他ドメインで新たにwordpressをダウンロード、問題なさそうな箇所を少しずつバックアップから移してみようと思っています。

Comment: @PicoSushi様　エラー表記部の編集、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

先ほどWPのバージョンを落として4.9.7にてダウングレードしてみたところ、復旧しました。

通常の手動アップデートと同じように、wp-admin・wp-includes他データを入れ替えたのがよかったのか、なんとか管理画面には入れました。

エラー前と設定が若干違っていたり、プラグインで作っていたページの見栄えが崩れたりはしていますが…やはりプラグインを更新した影響でか何か根本的なデータが書き変わってしまっていた可能性がありそうです。

何がおかしくなっていたのか不明ですが、取敢えず管理画面に入れない不具合は解決したため、質問を上げさせていただきましたが解決済とさせていただきます。
みなさまありがとうございました。